# Supress grep output but capture it in a variable

Tags: bash, grep

I'm trying to get the following line to work

```
WERRORS=`echo $VALPG | grep -q -s -o -m 1 '\<[0-9]* Errors'`
```

What I want is that the result of grep go into WERRORS variable but not echo in the terminal.
So i use -q, but then WERRORS is empty

Comment: Can you give an example for what would be in $VALPG?

Comment: What you have should work (if you drop the `-q`).  But it wouldn't hurt to add quotation marks: `"$VALPG"` rather than `$VALPG`.

Answer (score 1):

If grep sends any error messages, they go to the error output, which is not captured by the backticks. If you need this output in a variable (which is somewhat problematic, because it's often localized), redirect it using 2>&1:

```
WERRORS=`echo $VALPG | grep -s -o -m 1 '\<[0-9]* Errors' 2>&1`
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WERRORS=`echo $VALPG | grep -s -o -m 1 '\<[0-9]* Errors'`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
kent$  val=abcpc

kent$  a=$(echo $val|grep -o -m 1 -s 'pc')                                                                                               

kent$  echo $a
pc
```